# WordPress Child Theme: How do I add a custom style sheet from my parent theme to my child theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My parent theme has a style sheet: app/assets/css/screen.css which contains all of the theme's style for some reason instead of being in /style.css

Since I am customizing the theme I have set up a child theme but the changes that I add into my child theme's style.css don't work.

How can I add the app/assets/css/screen.css stylesheet to my child theme so I can make the necessary modifications?

Comment: Might be your child theme style.css file is loading before the app/assets/css/screen.css - Post your WordPress related question in the Wordpress Stack Exchange

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way of enqueuing the parent theme stylesheet currently is to add a `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and use `wp_enqueue_style()` in your child theme’s `functions.php`.

Load your `style.css` file with a proper handler as you said you have more than one `style.css` file you will have to make sure to maintain all of the Parent Theme dependencies.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'prefix_theme_enqueue_scripts' ) ) {
    function prefix_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent_handler', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app/assets/css/screen.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child_handler',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array('parent_handler')
        );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','prefix_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
    }
}
```

where `parent_handler` is the same $handle used in the parent theme when it registers it’s stylesheet. Check your parent theme for handler